# How to determine where warning is caused in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a large set of MATLAB scripts that I'm trying to run in Octave. At some point, the following warning is being raised during execution:

```
warning: division by zero
```

How can I tell which file/function is causing this warning in Octave?

Comment: its a far shot, but is there a "pause on warnings" option in Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `debug_on_warning` function, which does what you ask.

From the documentation:

```
'debug_on_warning' is a built-in function from the file libinterp/corefcn/error.cc

 -- VAL = debug_on_warning ()
 -- OLD_VAL = debug_on_warning (NEW_VAL)
 -- debug_on_warning (NEW_VAL, "local")
     Query or set the internal variable that controls whether Octave
     will try to enter the debugger when a warning is encountered.

     When called from inside a function with the "local" option, the
     variable is changed locally for the function and any subroutines it
     calls.  The original variable value is restored when exiting the
     function.

     See also: debug_on_error, debug_on_interrupt.
```

---

<sub>PS. If your program is also generating other warnings, but you don't want to enter debug mode for those, you can use the `warning` function to change the specific behaviour for the `division by zero` warning, converting that to an error, and then use `debug_on_error` instead to get octave to drop into a debugging terminal as soon as that error occurs.</sub>

Comment: I added `warning('error', 'Octave:divide-by-zero')`, and then was able to print a stack trace on error. Thanks!